# Proper use of cv::VideoCapture

Tags: c++, opencv

I've been having some issues regarding capturing video from a live stream.

I open up the video with the open function of the cv::VideoCapture. However I need to manually ask when a frame is ready in something like this:

```
while (true){
   cv::Mat frame;
   if (videoCapture.read(frame)){
      // Do stuff ...
   }
   else{
      // Video is done.
   }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it will definitely process a single frame multiple times, the number of times depending on the camera's FPS. This is because the read() function will only return false if the camera is disconnected, according to the documentation.

So my question is, how can I know if there is a NEW frame available? That I'm not just getting the old one again?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation of VideoCapture::read(...)](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1)? The first sentence says "Grabs, decodes and returns the next video frame." i.e. Every call should acquire a new frame. Based on what do you conclude that this is not happening?

Comment: It can't happen. If you grab a frame every 5 ms of a 30 fps camera, something is not right. It probably returns the last frame again. But point is, if the processing is expensive you can't process FullHD frames willy nilly. So you need to KNOW that this is effectively a new frame. I've concluded that I needed to change my timer to correspond with the fps that I know, beforehand, is that of the recording device.